# why i don't see destructor being called in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, destructor

I'm working on an API written in `python`. I'm using [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python) article as my help for `python` destructors.

```
# api.py
class ApiCfg(object):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        # open a connection to a device
        some_device_open()

    def __del__(self):
        print 'Close a connection to some_device'
        # close a connection to a device
        some_device_close()

# Some code
...
api_cfg = ApiCfg()

# myfile.py
from api import *

# Do some stuff
api.run()
```

What I'm expecting to see on my screen, once everything is done is a following statement: `Close connection to some device`. However for some reason I don't. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Did you create instance of `A` class? If yes, please show exactly how you call it. You need first to create instance of it and store at some variable. Then it will be automatically destructed on exit and __del__ will be executed.

Comment: @RustemK Sorry. I made a mistake. `A` is meant to be `ApiCfg`. Fixing it now.

Comment: Yeah, Python doesn't actually guarantee that `__del__` is called. `__del__` is not reliable. It's even less reliable on alternate Python implementations, and the standard implementation makes no guarantees that the ref-counting mechanism will remain in place. Python is not C++; trying to rely on `__del__` like you would rely on C++ destructors is a bad idea.

Comment: @user2357112 So what is the recommendation to close the device connection?

Comment: `with` statements, mostly.

Answer (score 3):

First of all **del** does not guarantee that it will be called. It's a 'problem' with certain garbage collectors, namely: circular referencing.

In your particular case I see that on init phase `ApiConfig.__init__` you opened connection to some device. It means that you probably incremented a reference counter on your object (and vice versa). Usually when user deals with the devices (file, socket, pipe) he should manage openning/closing it by himself, because **del** will not be called until reference counter to its object is equal to 0. That is why we usually use `with` clause to wrap execution of a block that manages device lifecycle properly. For example:

```
with open("filename") as f:
     for line in f:
        pass
```

you can define your own with clause by using [contextlib.contextmanager](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/contextlib.html) decorator or if you need more sophisticated logic, then create a class with **enter** and **exit** methods. You can check more in doc and looking at this [article](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/).

Also you can do it in more straightforward fashion by just creating and then calling `open()` and `close()` methods that are responsible for proper device handling (including proper closing of the device and its gc).

Comment: @flashburn what do u think? Satisfiable answer?

Answer (score 0):

The object is still referenced even when all the operations have been done. If you want to see this line appear, kill the program after the object creation. Python must destruct every object, so the `__del__` method will be run.

However, as pointed out in the comments, Python does not guarantee that this method will be called. Since Python works with a garbage collector, you are not supposed (or rather, not expected) to destruct manually the objects. If you want to be sure your `__del__` method is called, call the `del` statement.

Comment: So what would be the recommendation to close the connection with a device?

Comment: @flashburn Manually close it. There should be a `close` method of some sort, no matter what the device is. Put it in a `finally` block if there's a chance that exceptions could otherwise prevent closing. Alternately, if it supports use as a context manager, use a `with` statement.

Comment: @flashburn Yes, I would recommend to design your class so it supports context management. This is very handy to use.

Comment: @Rightleg So how would I design it in such a way that when it is deleted the device connection is closed, I can't really visualize it.

Comment: @flasburn Context management works this way: 1 - Create your object with `with` statement (underlying `__enter__` method); 2 -Create a new scope (ie, indent); 3 - Do your stuff; 4 - Close the scope (ie, unindent), which calls the `__exit__` method. Basically, `__enter__` creates and return an object, and `__exit__` does what is necessary to delete it the clean way. Anyway, when you leave the context scope, the object is not referenced anymore, so you don't have to delete it manually (because Python). But typically, `__exit__` should close files, etc.

Comment: @flashburn `__enter__` and `__exit__` should be implemented by your class, in order to support the `with` statement.

Comment: @Rightleg Thanks. It looks like there is no more need to do it with `__enter__` and `__exit__`.  [This documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/contextlib.html) shows how to implement it without them.